# CASCADE DELETE on last matching reference (Foreign key on composite primary key)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, composite-key

I have multiple events with the same **id** (event.id) but different **languages** (event.lang), whereby **id** and **lang** form a composite primary key of table *event*. An event can be represented by multiple records in the *event* table (one record per language). The records in the **n:m** mapping table *event_company_map* define a unique relation between a company and an event regardless of the event language.

```sql
-- events
CREATE TABLE `event` (
    `id` INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `lang` INT(3),
    `title` VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `lang`),
    INDEX `lang` (`lang`),
)

-- companies
CREATE TABLE `company` (
    `id` INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)

-- n:m relation table mapping events and companies
CREATE TABLE `event_company_map` (
    `event_id` INT(10),
    `company_id` INT(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`, `company_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `event` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Let's say, there are three events with an event.id = 42, each having a unique language id (event.lang) e.g. 1,2 and 3. Now, when I delete one event record (id = '42',  lang = 1) the mapping record with event_id = 42 in 'event_company_map' will be deleted no matter if there are still other events with id = 42 left.

I'd like to have the delete cascaded ONLY when the last event reference with id 42 gets deleted. How could I achieve that in MySQL?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the falw is in the design. You should rename the table `event` to `event_language` and create a new table called `event` (with `event_id` as primary key). Then change the FK from `event_company_map` to reference that new table.

Comment: What you are doing now, having a foreign key that references a column that is not the primary key, is dangerous anyway and should be avoided (other DBMS do not even allow it, for good reasons.)